# Getting multiple ints from string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string:

```
"3, V, 11, H, 21, H"
```

and I am trying to get

```
int first = 3
int second = 11
int third = 21
```

I'm not exactly sure how to do this since the numbers could be one or two digits, there are non-digit characters between the numbers, and I have to capture multiple numbers. I tried regex but then I'm left with "31121" which does not indicate what the three numbers are.

Comment: `I tried regex but then I'm left with "31121"` Can we see your code that generates this output? Also it seems that your data are in format `number, data, number, data, number, data,...`. In that case you can just split your input on comma and parse every even indexed elements to integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. Should get you the job done.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = "3, V, 11, H, 21, H";
    String[] t = s.split(" [ ,]*|,[ ,]*");
    int first = Integer.parseInt(t[0]);
    int second = Integer.parseInt(t[2]);
    int third = Integer.parseInt(t[4]);
    System.out.println(first);
    System.out.println(second);
    System.out.println(third);
}
```

Comment: you should use `.trim()`. I think `t[2]` would be " 11"

Comment: @mikeyaworski no, it's not

Comment: Oh because you split it with the space included. Well it'll work, but only under these perfectly strict conditions.

Comment: @mikeyaworski just made it much better

Answer (score 1):

You can split your String by `","` and check if it's a number using  [`NumberUtils.isNumber (String str)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isNumber%28java.lang.String%29) from `org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils` :

> Checks whether the String a valid Java number.
>
> Valid numbers include hexadecimal marked with the 0x qualifier,
>   scientific notation and numbers marked with a type qualifier (e.g.
>   123L).
>
> Null and empty String will return false.

```
String s = "3, V, 11, H, 21, H";
for(String st : s.split(",")){
    if(NumberUtils.isNumber(st.trim()))
        System.out.println(st);
}
```

If you want to check that the String contains only digits, you can use [`NumberUtils.isDigits(String str)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isDigits%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String in = "3, V, 11, H, 21, H";

    List<String> storage = Arrays.asList(in.split(","));
    List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int first = 0;
    int second = 0;
    int third = 0; 

    for(String str : storage){
        if(str.trim().matches("[0-9]+") ){ // or if(NumberUtils.isNumber(str) )
            output.add(Integer.parseInt(str.trim()));
        }
    }

    if(output.size() == 3){
         first = output.get(0);
         second = output.get(1);
         third = output.get(2);
    }

    System.out.print("first: "); System.out.println(first);
    System.out.print("second: "); System.out.println(second);
    System.out.print("third: "); System.out.println(third);

}
```

Output:

```
first: 3
second: 11
third: 21
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split this string by **`,`** and then check if every part is a number like this :

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String str = "3, V, 11, H, 21, H";
        String[] parts = str.split(", ");
        ArrayList<Integer> listNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(String x : parts){
         try{
           listNumbers.add( Integer.parseInt(x) );  
         }
         catch(Exception e){}    
        }

        for(int i=0;i<listNumbers.size();i++) System.out.println("Number "+(i+1)+" : "+listNumbers.get(i));
    }

}
```